# Counting with php and decimals (opencart)

Tags: php, count, opencart

I'm want to count two values that I get back from opencart. First is a fixed **price** and the other is an **option price**. When I print them I get the right numbers like: `$price = 10.25;` and `$option = 5.25;`. But when I say: `$total = $price + $option;` I get just 15. But I want 15.50. What am I doining wrong?

```
<?php
  $price = 10.25;
  $option = 5.25;
  $total = $price + $option;

  print $total; (will print just 15)
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot recreate: http://codepad.viper-7.com/smPP05

Comment: Thanks steve, guess I missching something in opencart than.

Answer (score 2):

Your php example is missing a $ sign before option.

```
 $total = $price + $option;
```

Answer (score 1):

Retype it to float:

```
$total = (float)$price + (float)$option;

echo (float)$total;
```

So, its OpenCart problem, read more about that here:

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=96706

As its written there, it is a know issue and should be solved in OC 2.0

Comment: Thanks, but float is nog woring :( Other ideas?

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the problem. I just found the problem but not yet the solution. OC is working with the  english/american notation and I am using the Europian notation. It has problems with the ,/.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change option into $option